# Advanced Configuration Product

Tags: magento2, configurable-product

I'm looking for a solution for configuration product in Magento. Please see this website http://www.photomart.com.au/product/print/

- Customer can upload multiple images in product frontend
- Relationship between product attributes. For example: Attribute Paper Type and Presentation only display once "Product Size" selected.
- When you change "Product Size" value, its children atributes (paper type and presentation) values will be changed as well.

Do you guys know any extension in Magento meet this requirements?

Thank you for your time!